# Unable to insert time after 19:59:00 in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am not unable to insert the time value 20:00:00 or more than that. It works good when the time is 00:00:00 to 19:59:00. I could not figure as it works good for 19 hrs. I am new for developing. I have made several effort to figure it out. But I could'nt. Please help me. I have added the html, php coding below and the mysql 'attendance' table.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `shift_start_time` time NOT NULL,
      `empid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `checkin` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
      `checkout` datetime NOT NULL,
      `worked_hours` time NOT NULL,
      `latehours` time NOT NULL,
      `late_seconds` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Break1` time NOT NULL,
      `Break1out` time NOT NULL,
      `Break1hours` time NOT NULL,
      `Break2` time NOT NULL,
      `Break2out` time NOT NULL,
      `Break2hours` time NOT NULL,
      `Lunch_Break` time NOT NULL,
      `Lunch_Breakout` time NOT NULL,
      `Lunch_Breakhours` time NOT NULL,
      `A_Break` time NOT NULL,
      `A_Breakout` time NOT NULL,
      `A_Breakhours` time NOT NULL,
      `A_BreakReason` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
      `totalbreak` time NOT NULL,
      `workhrs` time NOT NULL,
      `meeting_hours` time NOT NULL,
      `checkindate` date NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=350 ;




<form action="checkincheckout.php" method="post"><table><tr><td><label  for="line_items"                                                                    >
                                                                  <p class="text-info">Check In</p>
                                                                  </label><input type="radio" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Project Name" name="checkin" value="<?php 
                                                                                                echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?> " >
    </td><td><label  for="line_items"                                                                    >
                                                                  <p class="text-info">Check Out</p>
                                                                  </label><input type="radio" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Project Name" name="checkout" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit" >


    </script></td></tr></table></form>

//checkingcheckout.php

     if(isset($_POST['checkin']))
        {
            //$checkin =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $_POST['checkin']);
                 $checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
                 $checkindate=substr('$checkin',0,10);

                 if($checkin>$_SESSION['START_TIME'])
                 {
                    $timeDiff=strtotime($checkin)-strtotime($_SESSION['START_TIME']);



    $init = $timeDiff;
    $hours = floor($init / 3600);
    $minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
    $seconds = $init % 60;

    echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
    $ela=$hours.'+'.$minutes.'+'.$seconds;

                      $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `attendance`(shift_start_time,empid,user,checkin,latehours,late_seconds,checkindate) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['START_TIME']."','".$_SESSION['USERNAME']."','".$_SESSION['NAME']."','$checkin','$ela','$timeDiff','$checkindate')"); 
                 }
```

Comment: What happens when you try to add `20:00:00` ? Please add `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of your last line ( `$sql = mysql_query(...) or die(...)` )

Comment: The time is not at all getting inserted. I have checked in database too.

Comment: And what is the message ?

Comment: I got this following error when I have added or die(mysql_error):'-27:-5:-25Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Comment: Simplify..  You dont need to put the date in the radio value.  Just send an arbitrary value of 1 - so that you know that it has been clicked.
Also, you don't need to process date so much, just generate it in the format that you need for the database - $checkin = date("Y-m-d");

Comment: Looks like there is an empty cariable or something like that... can you lost every variables present in your query ? including SESSION ones ?

Comment: No I didnt lose any session variables

Comment: As other comments / answer say, this is a date format issue. format your date as MySQL awaits.

Answer (score 0):

Before we insert to table, php time should be converted to my sql compatible time format. You can use the below code for that

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i A', $php_time);
$sql_time = $date->format( 'H:i:s');
```

- $php_time - time format in php
- $sql_time - time format in mysql

Answer (score 0):

So you need to convert the Time formats from `PHP` to `MYSQL`

This is example and I have tested it

```
$time_from_input = date("y-m-d", (strtotime($_POST['time']));
```

Now this time is converted into MYSQL format.

For vice versa case. MYSQL time to PHP we need to change the format you want to display. just search or play with `date()` function.